# Is there a way to type engineering powers in Maple?

Tags: maple

Instead of typing 31600, can I use 31.6k?

I've tried to use but it doesn't work.

I also, would like to use other powers like micro, mili, nano...

Comment: "engineering powers" $\to$ "powers of thousands"

Comment: Define variables such as $K:=1000$. Then you can do $31.6*K$

Comment: If I remember correctly, Maple uses a capital E for this (i.e. 3.4E5 would give 340000)

Comment: `31.6e3` is equivalent to `31600.` For micro, you can use `31.6e-6` which is equivalent to `0.0000316`.

Comment: I personally think you should always work in SI units, everything else is just confusing and error-prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your question leads to two possible solutions:

1) You can use the *E*-notation, which works in Maple. The following are equivalent:

```
31.6e3;
31.6E3;
31600.;
```

This works for small numbers also. The following are equivalent:

```
31.6e-6;
31.6E-6;
0.0000316;
```

2) The [`units`](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Units) package.

```
31600.*Unit(mm);
convert(%,units,'m');
```